# How to iterate using IEnumerator in C#?

Tags: c#

I am working with [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) and I need to extend this class with Extension method [ElementAtOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.110).aspx). I have a trouble of doing this.

```
public static Request ElementAtOrDefault(this IEnumerable<Request> source, int index)
{
    IEnumerator<Request> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    // using enumerator return source[index]            
}
```

Than I am using this method:

```
ConcurrentQueue<Request> requestsInWork = new ConcurrentQueue<Request>();
//...
IEnumerable<Request> requests = requestsInWork as IEnumerable<Request>;
Request currenrRequest = requests.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
```

Can you provide me some example pls?

I implement ElementAtOrDefault by myself because I got error in second piece of code I added:

```
Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FCWebService.Request>' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAtOrDefault' and no extension method 'ElementAtOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FCWebService.Request>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Not sure what's your question. Are you reimplementing `ElementAtOrDefault` ? Are you aware of [ElementAtOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) exist in BCL?

Comment: There already is an extension method ElementAtOrDefault. Why implement it yourself?

Comment: I implement it by myself because I got error in second piece of code I added: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FCWebService.Request>' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAtOrDefault' and no extension method 'ElementAtOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FCWebService.Request>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @luliia: So wouldn't it be better to do as the error suggested (add the missing using directive or assembly reference) rather than reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Try to add `using System.Linq`

Comment: For future reference: Look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386(v=vs.110).aspx) page for the `ElementAtOrDefault` extension method (it's really easy to find with Google) and then look at the top of that page. It says `Namespace:  System.Linq`: this is the `using` statement you need. It also has `Assembly:  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)`: this is the assembly reference you need (which you probably already have).

Comment: This isn't going to be a safe operation to perform on a `ConcurrentQueue`.  By the time this method returns that item could already have been removed from the queue, or another item could be at that position, or any number of other possibilities.

Comment: @Servy, is it thread-safe to use default ElementAtOrDefault on ConcurrentQueue?

Comment: @Iuliia No, it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when the compiler can't find the extension method. Try to add the follwing statement `using System.Linq` in order to tell the compiler where to search for the extension method.

---

There's already an extension method [ElementAtOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) defined in the namespace `System.Linq`. First I didn't think of that and suggested following approach:

Instead of implementing everything on your own, maybe you could just use the existing extension methods `Skip` and `FirstOrDefault` like this:

```
public static Request ElementAtOrDefault(this IEnumerable<Request> source, int index)
{
 if(index<0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
  return source.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Why on earth he needs this over [Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Request ElementAtOrDefault(this IEnumerable<Request> source, int index)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    var notDone = true;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < index && (notDone = enumerator.MoveNext()))
        i++;
    return notDone ? enumerator.Current : default (Request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int count = 0;

foreach(var request in enumerator) {
   if(count == index)
      return request;
   count++;
}

return null;
```

Comment: Should probably return `default(Request)` rather than null, although I suspect that `Request` is probably a reference type anyway.

Comment: It should probably a generic method, but I'm just answering the question.  :)